# What did Freeman Dyson mean when he said this?

Tags: terminology, statistics, data-analysis, models

In this [video](https://youtu.be/hV41QEKiMlM), Freeman Dyson, when speaking of Fermi said the following thing,

> "...what does he think about the numerical agreement, and he said, 'How many parameters did you use for the fitting? How many free parameters are there in your method?' So I counted up. It turned out there were four. And he said, 'You know, Johnny von Neumann always used to say, "With four parameters I can fit an elephant, and with five I can make him wiggle his trunk."

My question is that what did he mean when used the word *parameter*?

My guess is that he is talking about the variational parameters in Wave function, but I don't get the idea how that is not allowed to be fair for precise measurements.